# Nilpotent map and upper triangular matrix

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, vector-spaces

If we have a map $\phi:V\rightarrow V$ on a vector space $V$ that is nilpotent, then there exists a basis $\underline{\mathbf{v}}$ such that the matrix of $\phi$ with respect to basis $\underline{\mathbf{v}}$, namely $M_{\underline{\mathbf{v}}}(\phi)$ is strictly upper triangular.

I am not sure why this is the case? Any help would be much appreciated!

Comment: There are a few approaches one could take to this problem. Are you aware of the general fact that, for any map $\phi$, there exists a basis that makes $M(\phi)$ upper triangular (but not necessarily strictly upper triangular)?

Answer (score 1):

$\newcommand{\span}{\operatorname{span}}$All its eigenvalues are $0$, so I can pick (at least one) some nonzero linearly independent vectors $\{v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k\}$ such that $\phi\equiv0$ on the span of $\{v_i\}$. I am doing this for the largest possible $k=\dim\ker\phi$.

If $k=n:=\dim V$, we are done as the matrix for $\phi$ is the $0$ matrix in this and any basis. Suppose $k\lt n$. Using the [Steinitz Exchange Lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Steinitz_exchange_lemma), there must exist nonzero vectors $b_{k+1},b_{k+2},\cdots,b_{k+k'}$, independent of each other and of the $v_i$, such that $\phi(b_{k+j})\in\span\{v_i\}$ for all $1\le j\le k'$. If this were not true, then $\phi$ could not possibly be nilpotent as the $\span\{v_i\}$ accounts for all vectors in the kernel of $\phi$. More formally I've used the lemma to build a basis of $\ker\phi+\phi^{-1}(\ker\phi)$ starting with a basis for $\ker\phi$, and $\phi^{-1}\ker\phi$ is nontrivial by nilpotency. If $k+k'=n$, we are done! Do you see why?

We can iterate this process, to choose a new set of linearly independent vectors (from themselves and all the basis vectors chosen thus far) $b_{k+k'+1},b_{k+k'+2},\cdots,b_{k+k'+k''}$ such that $\phi\{b_{k+k'+1},\cdots,b_{k+k'+k''}\}\subseteq\span\{b_{k+1},b_{k+2},\cdots,b_{k+k'}\}$, i.e. they combine to form a basis for $\phi^{-2}\ker\phi+\phi^{-1}\ker\phi+\ker\phi$. Inductively iterate until $k^{(j)}=n$. We know for sure that this process will terminate since $\phi$ is nilpotent.

Then $v_1,v_2,\cdots,v_k,b_{k+1},b_{k+2},\cdots,b_{k+k'},b_{k+k'+1},\cdots,b_{k+k'+k''},\cdots,b_n$ will form a basis for $V$, by construction, and also by construction if we build a matrix of $\phi$ with the basis vectors in that order, the matrix is strictly upper triangular (all $0$s on the main diagonal). Really make sure you see why that is, and feel free to ask.

Comment: Thank you for this, I am able to follow most of it!

Comment: For the part of it which you don't follow, please ask @maddiemoo